# Ionic template cache doesn't work on device, only in browser

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-templatecache

I implemented *gulp-angular-templatecache-ionic* to my Ionic app, which made my application run significantly faster in my desktop chrome browser, but when I build and deploy (ionic run android) this application to my device (LG Nexus 5x) it is still slow, it looks like nothing has changed, as if the built android version does not use the angular template cache.
I followed this article: http://tombuyse.com/improving-the-performance-of-your-ionic-application/

Any ideas or suggestions how to debug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug your WebView app please follow this guide from google
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

If your android version is less than 4.4, then you cannot debug through the chrome devtools.

you can instead run an emulator via the adb emulator, you'll need the android sdk and the adb tool.
read more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html

The default android emulator/simulator is slow, and also need the HAXM accelerator, you can download the Genymotion simulator which is a replacement for the default android emulators, and run faster, also doesn't need to change anything in your hardware configuration

https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Thanks man, the chrome stuff was new to me and it's a useful stuff indeed! My problem's source is not the template-cache, but the lack of angular-knowledge :) :(